# android kernel compiling error for arm64 (msm8996)

Tags: android, arm64

I'm trying to compile my custom kernel for an arm64 android device having an msm8996 SOC. I cloned my Kernel on GitHub just to make sure I have a fully clean code. Then I exported these:

```
export PATH=/home/nico/Downloads/kernel/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin:$PATH
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
export ARCH=arm64
export SUBARCH=arm64
```

Keep in mind that the msm8996 has two dual-core clusters which are both arm64. I tried compiling using the stock gcc 4.9 toolchain which is shiped with the Cyanogenmod sources and then I tried it using two of the UberTC 4.9 toolchains which can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/UBERTC/
aarch64-linux-android-4.9-kernel and aarch64-linux-android-4.9 (I dunno exactly what's the difference between those two).
Every time I retried building my kernel I performed a

```
make mrproper
```

and also deleted the ccache folder. Then I performed a

```
make cm_pme_defconfig
```

and finally a

```
make -j2
```

I also tried the same procedure with

```
make -j1
```

I couldn't find anyone else who got the same error so I decided to post it here.
Here's the error message in my terminal:

```
In file included from drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace.h:81:0,
                 from drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa.c:32:
include/trace/define_trace.h:83:43: fatal error: ./rndis_ipa_trace.h:
No such file or directory
#include TRACE_INCLUDE(TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE)
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
```

Furthermore here's my kernel on my GitHub https://github.com/nico151999/android_kernel_htc_msm8996

I really need your help though the solution to the problem may be quite obvious. Thanks a lot in advance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually based on this [commit](https://github.com/aznrice/kernel_google_msm/commit/e41494c15d4df342854ac3d2940f5d6ac3158212) i found global answer 
take look :

```
diff --git a/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h b/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h
index d70abdf..7f7e452 100644
--- a/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h
+++ b/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h
@@ -131,5 +131,5 @@ TRACE_EVENT(

 /* This part must be outside protection */
 #undef TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH
-#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH .
+#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH ../../drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2
 #include <trace/define_trace.h>
```

do this ("../../") to other TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: This is true, and helped me solving this issue.
The default TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH is the same as <trace/define_trace.h>'s path, which is normally kernel_root_dir/include/trace. By going up two directories (../../) and including the path for the c file that references <trace/define_trace.h>, you can fix any of such compilation errors without hardcoding your build path.
In my case I changed define ``#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH .`` to ``#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH ../../drivers/net/ethernet/msm/``, which is the path for ``rndis_ipa_trace.h``, thus solving the problem the OP had, which is equal.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the exactly same issue with Qualcomm kernel. Generally, adding 
    CFLAGS_trace.o := -I$(src)
to correct Makefile could fix this build issue. But it didn't work for me. So I used a very bold method. Patch is like following:

```
diff --git a/drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace.h b/drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace.h
index c0fc573..c18046b 100644
--- a/drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace.h
+++ b/drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace.h
@@ -77,5 +77,5 @@ TRACE_EVENT(

 /* This part must be outside protection */
 #undef TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH
-#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH .
+#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH /opt/work/qcom/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/msm/
 #include <trace/define_trace.h>
diff --git a/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h b/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h
index d70abdf..7f7e452 100644
--- a/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h
+++ b/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h
@@ -131,5 +131,5 @@ TRACE_EVENT(

 /* This part must be outside protection */
 #undef TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH
-#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH .
+#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH /opt/work/qcom/kernel/drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/
 #include <trace/define_trace.h>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to perform a Cyanogenmod build where a successfuly built kernel was the result. However, building just the kernel results in the error I posted. As it works alongside a Cyanogenmod ROM build I currently don't want to apply this patch. Anyway, when I want to build just the kernel again I will try it. Thanks a lot again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

It seems that you can modify **"TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH"** in the file **"rndis_ipa_trace.h"** for each directory. And, directories to be modified are included in the build error message.

As I proceeded with the build, I could find problems on the following path, and I proceeded with the build by referring to the solutions of the others above.

**drivers/clk/qcom/mdss/rndis_ipa_trace.h & drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/rndis_ipa_trace.h**

Thank you for your guide =)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled with the same problem as soon as I started working with Linux Kernel v3.18 - LineageOS source for Moto G5 (Qualcomm SD 430) at a few places.

Patch the file "drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace.h" @ line 15

```
- #define TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE rndis_ipa_trace
+ #define TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE ../drivers/net/ethernet/msm/rndis_ipa_trace
```

and  the file "drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace.h" @ line 15

```
- #define TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE ipa_trace
+ #define TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE ../drivers/platform/msm/ipa/ipa_v2/ipa_trace
```

Both changes were made to be less invasive and avoid modifying the file at "include/traces", which may be used by others C files. This is a more local solution than a general change. And also, does not need to worry with absolute paths for the files, the "#include" call has is root at "/path/to/source/linux/.", so if you use a relative path knowing it will start from there, the changes may work.